# How to pipe results of a foreach statement to a text file?

Tags: powershell, pdf, directory-listing, page-numbers, attributes

How do I pipe the results of the script below into a list.txt?

```
$folder = 'C:\Test'
$Total = $Files = 0

foreach($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.pdf)){
    $Pages = (pdfinfo $File.FullName | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=Pages:\s*)\d+').Matches.Value
    $Total += $Pages
    $Files++
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PdfFile = $File.Name
        Pages   = $Pages
    }
}
"`nTotalNumber of pages: {0} in {1} files" -f $Total,$Files
```

Comment: you can redirect output to a file using the `>` (or `>>` if you want to append to the file) operator. if you have a variable you want to save to file, you can just do `$var > c:\file.txt`

Comment: what part of the output do you want sent to a file? the `[PSCustomObject]` is not assigned to anything - so it is going to the success stream & then your screen. the `total number of pages` is going along the same path.

Comment: where are you getting `pdfinfo`? i cannot find a windows version anywhere ...

Comment: If you are new to Powershell, you may find it handy to find the online help topics directly from your broweser, without starting Powershell.  For example, if you tell your browser to search for "help about_redirection" you'll get the online version of the same thing you would see if you type this Help command in Powershell.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2